# How to bind a model.property to angular-2-material date picker's ngModel?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

**To begin**: I am trying to create a form using angular-2 material components. I have a form containing date picker:

```
        <md-form-field>
          <input readonly="true" mdInput [mdDatepicker]="regDatePicker" placeholder="{{'client.regdate-placeholder'}}">
          <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="regDatePicker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
          <md-datepicker #regDatePicker  startView="month" [startAt]="currentDate"></md-datepicker>
        </md-form-field>
```

TypeScript:

```
    public client: IPerson;
    @ViewChild("regDatePicker")
    public regDatePicker: MdDatepicker<Date>;
```

**Whats is needed**: either to bind date picker's ngModel to client.registrationDate, or to set value of regDatePicker from code behind.

**What i get:**: in case of [(value)] binding, i see error that

```
Can't bind to 'mdDatepicker' since it isn't a known property of 'input'
```

trying to set it in code behind, but can't find proper name of property or field to set value to.

**Question**: What should I do in order to bind data from model?

**UPD:** Added code that refers to Input

```
@ViewChild("dpDateInput")
public dpDate: MdDatepickerInput<Date>;

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   console.log(`---------->>>>>>>>> before ${ this.dpDate.value}`)
   this.dpDate.value = this.client.regDate;
   console.log(`---------->>>>>>>>> after ${ this.dpDate.value}`);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code with which you refer to the value?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `mdDatepickerInput` instead of `mdDatepicker` while referring to the `value`.

**EDIT**

One way to reflect changes to the UI would be by injecting `ChangeDetectorRef` to the component's constructor and calling its `detectChanges()` method.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor (private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   console.log(`---------->>>>>>>>> before ${ this.dpDate.value}`)
   this.dpDate.value = this.client.regDate;
   this.ref.detectChanges();
   console.log(`---------->>>>>>>>> after ${ this.dpDate.value}`);
}
```

Comment: I added code (it uses your suggestion), but that didnt work for me. Console shows that the value actually did change, but UI is not updated